# How to put a value into the shortest row of a 2 dimensional array java

Tags: java, arrays

So basically what I am doing is trying to assign a new Object into the shortest row of a 2-Dimensional Array, the shortest row is determined by a feature of the object stored in the array(in this case minutes) I already have a method that sums the min's up for each individual row of the array but I believe my if statements are off. any advice or ideas would be great.

Here is what I have so far

```
public static boolean addCustomer(TattooCustomer [][] a, TattooCustomer c) 
{
    boolean x=false;
    for(int row=0; row<a.length-1; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<a[row].length; col++)
        {
            if((computeMinutesOfWork(a[row])<computeMinutesOfWork(a[row+1]))&&(a[row][col]==null))
            {
                a[row][col] = c;
                x = true;
            }
            else if((computeMinutesOfWork(a[row])<computeMinutesOfWork(a[row+1]))&&(a[row][col]!=null)&&(a[row+1][col]==null))
            {
                a[row+1 ][col] = c;
                x = true;
            }


            else
            {
                x = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

}

Comment: You only compare the current and the next rows here. You could compute the "cost" of every row first (basically a min find?) and only then assign the object to the smallest.

Comment: I used this to figure out the problem, thank you so much